# Universal link does not work. Link validator tool displays error:Error no apps associated with url

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, nsuseractivity, associated-domains

I followed all the steps for adding universal link support for an app.  But the option to open the app is never displayed.

- The server hosts apple-app-site-association file with the following contents:

{

```
"applinks": {

    "apps": [],

    "details": [

        {

            "appID": "teamID.bundleID'",

            "paths": [ "/ios/meetings"]

        }

    ]

}
```

}

- Device logs for when app is installed:

swcd(CoreUtils)[216] : Completing request for 'https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association', status 0/0x0 noErr

swcd(CoreUtils)[216] : Updated app ID 'teamID.bundleID', domain '*.example.com', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x2 < SiteApproved > on check

- Hitting URL: https://example.com/ through apps like mail, messages, notes, and safari always opens the link in the browser.
- Link validator tool displays status passed but the section "Link to Application" displays an error: Error no apps associated with URL.

Can anyone tell me if I am missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set paths to ["*", "/"] and also goto Project-->Targets-->Capabilities-->Associated Domain "ON".

Comment: @DixitAkabari Thanks. It worked with the path set to [*].

Comment: Happy to help you . please mark as a right if u satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1 set paths to ["*", "/"]

and

2 goto Project-->Targets-->Capabilities-->Associated Domain "ON"